# Fortigate's specs meaning

Tags: firewall

I am reading through the Fortigate's documentation to look for a device to replace the current device of my office(Draytek).

Is that true that I should depend on the **Firewall throughput** to choose the suitable device for my office, not depend on **how many users** do my office has?

Hope to hear your advice.

Comment: The number of users means nothing without a lot more information, e.g. the applications and how much bandwidth is used for each. Boiling that down, you end up with a throughput number, and that, along with pps, is what you need.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say choose (in case of performance) on throughput because you can have 10 users that heavily using network and can create more traffic and open more connections than 50 users.

Answer (score 1):

The performance parameters you should be looking for are

- the maximum throughput with the feature set you've got in mind (classic firewall, NGFW, UTM, AV, VPN, ...), according to your (future) uplink
- the maximum number of sessions which is more meaningfull that "users" - a quiet user might just use 100 sessions over a day and a busy user a thousand times that or more

Most low-end routers have very limited session capabilities, so they try to pass that off as "user capability". Sometimes however, the "user capability" is related to an artificial limitation of simultaneous IP endpoints by model or license. The Fortigates don't have that though.